# Threading ...start/suspend ..set/reset

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, manualresetevent

I have been trying to modify an app developed by other in past ...

this app does online trading ( using api developed for C#)..so basically i have the app structure where i set few configuration paramter which user can check or uncheck and there is start and stop button

on clicking start button..i am creating a thread by passing function which will do all aping and other stuff and assigning it to main form class

```
betbot _mybot = this; # mybot is form class
this.main_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(_mybot.aping_function);
this.main_thread.Start();
```

and on clicking stop button,,,app is simply suspending the thread

```
this.main_thread.Suspend()
```

now the app stops and only way to resume the app function (aping) is to press start button and relaunch thread..

As a new feature , i want this thread to stop and restart automatically ..every time it hits certain stop loss and start over...but i couldn't do it

what i have tired is **ManualResetEvent** as following

```
private static ManualResetEvent mrse = new ManualResetEvent(true);
```

when certain event matches in aping_function method i do mrse.reset() and mrse.set()..but that seems to have not effect( not restarting completely)

```
if (stop_loss_condition_met)
{
   this.Print1("Bot Is stopped Automatically");
   mrse.Reset();
   this.Print1("Bot Is re-started Automatically");
   mrse.Set();
}
```

how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You should add a call of the WaitOne method at the place where your worker thread should stop.

```
mrse.WaitOne()
```

at the next time when external code reset it by call

```
mrse.Reset()
```

the execution will be stopped and thread will go to sleep at point

```
mrse.WaitOne()
```

until external code call Set method of the ManualResetEvent

```
mrse.Set()
```

Comment: So i side my aping_function i create a while(true) { mrse.WaitOne() and then inside my if condition if i will do mrse.reset() and mrse.set() in same order ..next to. Next...thread will stop there and restart from WaitOne line..right ?